# How can I add tables to a database in Liferay with FreeMarker?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I want to add a table to my database using ***FreeMarker***.
I tried to use the [**ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil**](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/expando/service/ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.html) class in my template:

```
<#assign expandoTable = staticUtil["com.liferay.portlet.expando.service.ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil"] />
```

then I tried to add table:

```
<#assign table = expandoTable.addTable(theme_display.getCompanyId(),"", "MYTABLE") />
```

But the table is not added.

I also tried in this way:

```
${expandoTable.addTable(theme_display.getCompanyId(),"", "ANOTHER-TABLE")}
```

And I get this errors:

```
Template processing error: "Method public static 
com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoTable
com.liferay.portlet.expando.service.ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.addTable(long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException,com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException threw an exception"

    The problematic instruction:
    ----------
    ==> ${expandoTable.addTable(theme_display.getCompanyId(),"", "ANOTHER-TABLE")} [on line 22, column 1 in eventi-theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/portal_normal.ftl]
    ----------

    Caused by: com.liferay.portlet.expando.DuplicateTableNameException: {tableId=0}
```

Comment: And you have seen the `DuplicateTableNameException`?

Answer (score 3):

The Expando API does not create database-level tables, rather virtual tables. Check your database, and you'll find several "Expando" tables. They will contain all your data. The whole point of the Expando-API is that you can extend the data model without any new DDL-level operation (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`) on the database.

If you want to create separate tables, just do it - but don't use Expando for it.

And as the `DuplicateTableNameException` shows, your table has already been added.

Allow one architectural comment: I see freemarker (at least in the typical use) rather as a UI level option to extend Liferay and typically would expect this kind of operation rather in a backend component than in the frontend.